# First Known Client/Server Architecture Malware

Tags: malware, historical

What malware was the first to use a client-server architecture to relay commands?

The earliest that I could find appears to be NetBus which was written in [early 1998](https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/malicious/netbus-21-trojan-horse-actual-valid-remote-control-administration-tool-103). The next closest would be Back Orifice, which was written in [August 1998](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_Orifice).

However, these two pieces of malware were very popular, so I'm curious if there were any others which were discovered before then. I don't think backdoored versions of telnet count for this.

Comment: Before 1998, you start to blur the line between "malware" and simply "configuration". In Unix environments, you just built your own. Networking was very different and so was the sharing of files.